# How to add items to rdflist /rdfcollection dynamically in Jena

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, jena

Is it possible to add items dynamically to a RDFList in Jena?
Something like:

```
RDFList list = model.createList(new RDFNode[] {});
//string with names of rdf classes
String[] parts = list.split("-");

for(int i = 0; i<parts.length; i++){
    OntClass oclass = model.getOntClass("http://example.org/"+parts[i]);  
    list.add(oclass);
}
```

I'm getting 
`com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.EmptyListUpdateException: Attempt to add() to the empty list (rdf:nil)` 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing all of your code and what some of the values are, we can't be sure what's happening, but I think the problem here is that you can't use RDFList#add with an *empty* list, and I think that's what you're creating at the start.  Since you're creating a list with no elements, you should be getting **rdf:nil** back, which is the empty list.  Note that the documentation for [RDFList#add](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/rdf/model/RDFList.html#add-org.apache.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode-) says:

> If this list is the empty (nil) list, we cannot perform a side-effecting update without changing the URI of this node (from rdf:nil) to a blank-node for the new list cell) without violating a Jena invariant. Therefore, this update operation will throw an exception if an attempt is made to add to the nil list. Safe ways to add to an empty list include [with(RDFNode)](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/rdf/model/RDFList.html#with-org.apache.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode-) and [cons(RDFNode)](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/rdf/model/RDFList.html#cons-org.apache.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode-).

You didn't mention whether you're getting that exception or not.

In your case, I think the easiest thing to do would be to create the array of **OntClass**es, and then just create the list from them.  That is, you could do something like (untested):

```
String[] parts = list.split("-");
RDFNode[] elements = new RDFNode[parts.length];

for(int i = 0; i<parts.length; i++){
    elements[i] = model.getOntClass("http://example.org/"+parts[i]);  
}

RDFList list = model.createList(elements);
```

Alternatively, if you want to use **with**, as mentioned in the documentation, you'd do something like (again, untested):

```
RDFList list = model.createList(new RDFNode[] {});
//string with names of rdf classes
String[] parts = list.split("-");

for(int i = 0; i<parts.length; i++){
    OntClass oclass = model.getOntClass("http://example.org/"+parts[i]);  
    list = list.with(oclass);
}
```

For a bit more about this, you might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20568470/1281433) of mine and the comments on it relevant. You're not the first one to have had a bit of a struggle with RDFLists.